# Where to find Maven CXF 2.2.6 jar?

Tags: maven, jar, cxf

I'm converting an ANT project that uses CXF into a Maven one. The problem is that this projects depends on CXF v2.2.6 and when I go to [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.cxf/cxf/2.2.6) or even [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.cxf/apache-cxf/2.2.6), there is no jar to download. I don't know what to do. I have the JAR but I want to use the Maven features like dependency management.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using Ant, it likely used the cxf-bundle jar that pretty much contains all of CXF.   You can just add:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
  <artifactId>cxf-bundle</artifactId>
  <version>2.2.6</version>
</dependency>
```

to your new pom and it would get that jar along with all the dependencies that it would require.

Comment: What is the difference between cxf and cxf-bundle? And, I'm converting an Ant project to a Maven project, so my new project will only use Maven.

Answer (score 1):

It is [available at Maven central](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.apache.cxf%7Ccxf%7C2.2.6%7Cpom).  Use repo1.maven.org as your repository.

Comment: The thing is that repo1.maven.org (also known as "central") is the **default** repository (you can find it defined in Maven's super POM).  You can add other repositories directly in your project's POM (http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Repositories) or in your settings file (http://maven.apache.org/settings.html#Repositories)

Comment: Okay, so finally this JAR is not available on the central repository?

Comment: Nope it is there.  I just added it to my project and it was downloaded.  Are there any proxy issues maybe?

Comment: In my POM, the central repository has the URL http://repo1.maven.org/maven2, but I also added another repository with the URL you gave me(repo1.maven.org) and it doesn't work. I don't think there are network problems since I can download another dependencies from my IDE.

Comment: I apologize for not being clear.  When I said repo1.maven.org I really meant repo1.maven.org/maven2.  So you were ok with that.  Since network access doesn't seem to be the issue my next suspicion is the `packaging` element of the dependency.  Note that cxf has a packaging of `pom`.  All that said, looking at the contents of the POM it appears that what you really need is the cxf-bundle's POM.  Now this goes into the details of what is CXF and what it needs.  I'll let **you** be the judge of that.

Comment: I understand but even if the packaging is POM, when I add a dependency to my project, I specify the coordinates (org.apache.cxf,cxf,2.2.6,pom) and when I look at the Maven dependencies, I don't see any downloaded jar corresponding to CXF (no cxf, no cxf-bundle). Is there a special procedure to follow for pom types?

Comment: Maybe what you need is `cxf-bundle-2.2.6.jar`.  I hope this helps.  I will be offline for the next several hours....IOW not ignoring your posts :-P

Comment: Maybe, but i'm wondering why there is also a JAR org.apache:cxf:2.2.6 in the repository if we can get it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4837/discussion-between-sri-sankaran-and-mickael-marrache)

Answer (score 0):

Either [install it manually](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/install-file-mojo.html) to your local repository or use a repository manager like [Nexus](http://nexus.sonatype.org/).

Comment: Are you sure it's the only solution? How CXF may not be in Maven repositories? Also, all the CXF dependencies must be handled manually, right?